# IntelliJ constantly indexing, when src file is in focus

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a strange behavior of intellij.
It is constantly trying to reindex my project, as soon as i focus a src file like *.java.
This happens for any project. Even if i have a new project with a single src file.

I have resetted it to manufacturer state and it still tries to reindex.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04

Log output:
2020-08-18 05:02:02,004 [ 260523]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to index
2020-08-18 05:02:02,602 [ 261121]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 676357740)
2020-08-18 05:02:02,609 [ 261128]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 3ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok

I found this exception in logs which seems to be the root cause

> 2020-08-18 05:11:52,721 [ 126435]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed (trace_hash = 30135350)
> java.lang.Throwable
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerComponent.synchronizeRoots(ProjectRootManagerComponent.java:306)
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerComponent.fireRootsChangedEvent(ProjectRootManagerComponent.java:210)
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.fireRootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:428)
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.access$200(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:37)
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$BatchSession.rootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:96)
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.makeRootsChange(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:371)
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$RootProviderChangeListener.rootSetChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:668)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor532.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.dispatchVoidMethod(EventDispatcher.java:123)
> at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.lambda$createMulticaster$1(EventDispatcher.java:86)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174.rootSetChanged(Unknown Source)
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.RootProviderBaseImpl.fireRootSetChanged(RootProviderBaseImpl.java:47)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:980)
> at com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.impl.ProjectJdkImpl$MyRootProvider.rootsChanged(ProjectJdkImpl.java:291)
> at com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.impl.ProjectJdkImpl.copyTo(ProjectJdkImpl.java:267)
> at com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.impl.ProjectJdkImpl.commitChanges(ProjectJdkImpl.java:309)
> at com.intellij.codeInspection.magicConstant.MagicConstantInspection.lambda$attachAnnotationsLaterTo$1(MagicConstantInspection.java:182)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:201)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:802)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:322)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:84)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:132)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:47)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:188)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:967)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:839)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:450)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:802)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:497)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: Do you store file on local drive? Check the [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) file at the moment when it happens - what is printed there?

Comment: If you have generated files inside project (output of scripts, log files etc) please exclude such files (by [marking file as plain text](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#exclude-files)) or folders (by [setting folder as excluded](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#project_tool_window) ) from project so IDE does not re-index them on any change.

Comment: Added the log to the question. i will try to exclude autogenerated files

Comment: However. It is even doing this with a new java project, where no autogeneration does happen

Answer (score 1):

It is known issue: [IDEA-247322](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247322). The workaround is to disable Preferences | Editor | Inspections | Java | Probable bugs | **Magic Constant inspection**.

UPD: It is fixed with the 2020.2.3 IDE update.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, but i cannot explain it to myself.
I installed intellij over snap. This installation (not the settings) itself was causing this. This was reproducable by reinstalling over snap.
If i install the same build of intellij without snap, the issue does not occur.